# WebBrowser Control TextInput events

Tags: html, .net, wpf, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm struggling with the `WebBrowser` control (both in Winforms and WPF). Basically I want to achieve the same behavior I got with a `RTF` editor: Handling some kind of **`OnTextInput`** event in order to get the last typed character for every keystroke.

I mean the textual characters, not Control, Alt, F5, Enter, ... that can be captured with the `Keydown/Keyup` events.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do the content come from? Does the content come from an html file that belongs to you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the DesignMode combined with the NavigateToString in order to create HTML documents coming from a database.

Comment: And what do you want to do with handled key events?

Comment: I'm implementing a kind of "filter" so I need to know the characters that are being typed in order to apply the filtering on another list that I have.

Comment: So I think you will find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hanlde `KeyPress` event of `this.webBrowser1.Document.Body`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
    //Attach a handler to DocumentCompleted
    this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}


void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Attach a handler to Body.KeyPress when the document completed
    this.webBrowser1.Document.Body.KeyPress += Body_KeyPress;
}

void Body_KeyPress(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    //handle the event, for example show a message box
    MessageBox.Show(((char)e.KeyPressedCode).ToString());
}
```

**Note:**

- It doesn't handle non-input keys as you need.
- You can also suppress the input by setting `e.ReturnValue = false;` based on some criteria if you need.
- You can also handle other key events like `KeyUp` and `KeyDown` the same way

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand it. This way, the MessageBox will be displayed only half of the times, right? I want to compose a filter for every "textual" key pressed, so that I'm not sure if this will fit.

Comment: Showing the `MessageBox` is just a sample, you can use `((char)e.KeyValue).ToString()`. The main point is using `PreviewKeyDown` event that you asked for **Handling some kind of OnTextInput event in order to get the last typed character for every keystroke.** I think the post answers your question :)

Comment: Yes, but this way it's also being fired when F1, F2, Fx..., Ctrl, Alt, Mayus, ArrowLeft, ArrowRight, etc .... is there any "smart" way to prevent adding these kind of keystrokes?

The WPF RichTextBox control already provides a OnTextInput that is not fired on these cases.

Comment: Check the update, I think the edit contains what you are looking for.

Comment: @BorjaLópez I tested the solution and it works properly.

Comment: you got the right trick :)

By handling the KeyPress event, it's fired when a textual key is pressed, and also with the spacebar. I'm not sure if there's any other key that fires this KeyPress event ... could you please confirm?

On the other hand, the rest of keys (tab, ctrl, enter, delete, back, arrows, ...) fire the OnKeyUp event, so that it makes me take control of the event handling.

This is the answer I was looking for, so thank you very much!!

Comment: You are welcome :) *The KeyPress event is not raised by non-character keys other than space and backspace; however, the non-character keys do raise the KeyDown and KeyUp events.*

Comment: I have a couple of questions more about this control, but not regarding to the input text events ... Should I open a new question or extend this one?

Comment: Each post should contain one question. So if you searched for your other questions and not found suitable answers, you can open new questions for each topic.

Comment: Thanks Reza. I previously searched the forum and I did not find the proper solution. I'll post it as soon as I can.